# Build Error while trying to consume data from the API

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I am trying to consume the data from an API. Basically, the details I am trying to consume are location coordinates like (latitude and longitude). I tried the below code and it throws be an error in the build.

This is my Coordinates code I have tried

```
package TestAPI.java;

public class Coordinates {
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public double getLatitude(){
        return latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(double latitude){
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    public double getLongitude(){
        return longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(double longitude){
        this.longitude =longitude;
    }
    private String latitudeString(){
        double lat =getLatitude();
        String dir ="N";

        if(lat<0){
            dir="S";
            lat *= -1;
        }
        return ""+ lat +"°"+dir;
    }
    private String longitudeString(){
        double lng = getLongitude();
        String dir = "E";
        if(lng<0){
            dir="W";
            lng*=-1;
        }
        return""+ lng +"°" +dir;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return latitudeString() + "," + longitudeString();
    }
}
```

This is the application code I have tried.

```
package TestAPI.java;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Coordinates coordinates = restTemplate.getForObject("https://sample.com", Coordinates.class);
    }
}
```

Build gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-web")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Error

[image: Error description]

Answer (score 1):

This is internet issue, your maven cannot access remote central repository.

> Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org

- Ensure that you have an established internet connection.
- Ensure that you can access default maven repo http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 in your browser.
- Check if you have correct configuration in `<repositories>` and `<proxies>` in your your `settings.xml`